# res and src folder relation in eclipse android

Tags: android

What is the importance of "res" and "src" folders in eclipse-android while creating android project.

Answer (score 1):

`src` is where your source files go, `res` is where your resource files go (icons, images, externalised strings for internationalisation and so forth).

Answer (score 0):

src contains java classes.
res contains various stuff, including images to be used in your projects, layouts etc.